# How do I create a daemon which executes TimerTasks?

Tags: java, daemon

I need to create a daemon in Java which periodically retrieves data via HTTP and stores that in a database.

When the main thread starts up, it reads the data sources and poll intervals from a configuration file and creates a `TimerTask` with the appropriate interval for each data source. In addition, it calls `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook()` to add a shutdown hook which performs any cleanup needed before shutdown. After that, the main thread has nothing else to do.

The daemon is intended for use in a classic Unix environment, i.e. controlled with a start/stop script, though it should be portable to other OSes (say, Windows with SrvAny).

How would I go about this? If I just let the main thread exit, will the `TimerTask` instances keep the VM running until all of them have been cancelled? If not, how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the `Timer` on which the `TimerTask` was scheduled: if that `Timer` was created *not* to run its tasks as daemons, a pending `TimerTask` will keep the VM alive even after the main thread has finished its work. This is the case for all `Timer` constructors which do not take a `boolean` argument, or where the `boolean` argument is `false`.

The following seems to work as intended:

```
package com.example.daemon;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class SampleDaemon {
    private static Timer testTimer = new Timer(false);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Received shutdown request!");
                if (testTimer != null)
                    testTimer.cancel();
                testTimer = null;
            }
        });
        testTimer.schedule(new TestTimerTask(), new Date(), 2000);
    }

    private static class TestTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Still running…");
        }
    }
}
```

It prints `Still running…` every 2 seconds. When the JVM receives a `SIGTERM`, the program prints `Received shutdown request!` and exits. This can also be accomplished by sending Ctrl+C from the console. `SIGHUP` does the same as `SIGTERM`.

`SIGCONT` has no effect; `SIGUSR1` results in a hard exit (presumably the same as `SIGKILL`), i.e. without executing the shutdown hook.

Answer (score 1):

Threads in Java have a flag to indicate if they should keep the jvm alive or not. This flag is called "daemon": the jvm will exit when only daemon threads are running.

The thread started by Timer is not a daemon thread by default, so it will keep the jvm alive, which is what you want. If you wanted the jvm to exit, you could create the timer with `new Timer(true)` - this would set the daemon flag. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#%3Cinit%3E(boolean)